# Hybrid Application with Ionic/Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, yo

I'm developing my first hybrid application with Ionic/Cordova. I did the initial project setup with this generator: https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic

I also read a lot about the project structure. As far as I understood it, the plugins and platforms directory shouldn't be in version control. They are generated during the build process.

Now my question, where should I put the native android code? There is a class generated named CordovaApp in platforms/android//CordovaApp.java 
Is this the source folder ?

What about the platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml und platforms/android/build.xml files? Should they be under version control or not? If not where can i configure my Application Name like described here:
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/renaming-android-build-apk-from-cordovaapp-to-your-app-name/15416

regards
angela

Comment: on a cordova project, only the root www folder should be on version control

Answer (score 0):

You should start with reading the very detailed tutorial / guide on apache -> http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android Platform Guide